# Making an Online Examination website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I am making an online examination website where in which the users can attend the examination. I want to get a notification when the user minimizes or closes the website or opens a new tab. Can anyone tell me how to do that using languages like html css js php jQuery sql.

Comment: Do you want to do this in order to detect if the student is looking up the answers on the web? If so, it's not worth doing - they will just use another device, like a mobile phone.

Comment: actually its an intranet thing

Answer (score 2):

You may use **Javascript Window Object Model**

## Example

**Windows Closed Property:**
A function that checks whether a window called "myWindow" has been closed or not:

```
function checkWin() {
    if (!myWindow) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "'myWindow' has never been opened!";
    } else {
          if (myWindow.closed) { 
              document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "'myWindow' has been closed!";
          } else {
              document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "'myWindow' has not been closed!";
          }
    } 
}
```

**closed**: Returns a Boolean value indicating whether a window has been closed or not

**defaultStatus**:  Sets or returns the default text in the statusbar of a window

**document**:   Returns the Document object for the window (See Document object)

**frameElement**:   Returns the  element in which the current window is inserted

**frames**: Returns all  elements in the current window

**history**:    Returns the History object for the window (See History object)

**innerHeight**:    Returns the inner height of a window's content area

**innerWidth**: Returns the inner width of a window's content area

**length**: Returns the number of  elements in the current window

**location**:   Returns the Location object for the window (See Location object)

**createPopup()**:  Creates a pop-up window

**focus()**:    Sets focus to the current window

**moveBy()**:   Moves a window relative to its current position

**moveTo()**:   Moves a window to the specified position

**open()**: Opens a new browser window

**print()**:    Prints the content of the current window

**prompt()**:   Displays a dialog box that prompts the visitor for input

**resizeBy()**: Resizes the window by the specified pixels

**resizeTo()**: Resizes the window to the specified width and height

**scroll()**:   Deprecated. This method has been replaced by the scrollTo() method.

**scrollBy()**: Scrolls the document by the specified number of pixels

**scrollTo()**: Scrolls the document to the specified coordinates

**setInterval()**:  Calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds)

**setTimeout()**:   Calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds

**stop()**: Stops the window from loading

For more: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)